# Show that if $a,k\in \mathbb{Z}$ with $0\leq k \leq a$, then $\binom ak=\frac{a!}{k!(a-k)!}=\binom {a}{a-k}$.

Tags: real-analysis, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I'm reading Ghorpade's *A Course in Calculus and Analysis*.

> Given $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, the **binomial coefficient** associated with $a$ and $k$ is defined by:
>
> $$\binom ak =  
> \begin{cases}
>  \frac{a(a-1)\dots(a-k+1)}{k!} & \text{if }\ k \geq 0 \\
>  0 & \text{if }\ k < 0
> \end{cases}.$$
>
> Show that if $a,k\in \mathbb{Z}$ with $0\leq k \leq a$, then:
>
> $$\binom ak=\frac{a!}{k!(a-k)!}=\binom {a}{a-k}$$

I guess I've seen the second version of the binomial theorem, but I don't know how to prove the second through the first. I really have no clue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  {\binom ak}&=&{\frac{a!}{k!(a-k)!}} \\
  {}&&{}\\
  {\binom {a}{a-k}}&=&{\frac{a!}{(a-k)!(a-[a-k])!}} \\ 
  {}&&{}\\
  {}&=&{\frac{a!}{(a-k)!(a-a+k)!}} \\
  {}&&{}\\
  {}&=&{\frac{a!}{(a-k)!k!}} \\
  {}&&{}\\
  {}&=&{\frac{a!}{(a-k)!k!}} 
  {}&&{}\\
  {}&&{}\\
{\frac{a!}{k!(a-k)!}}&=&{\frac{a!}{(a-k)!k!}}\implies \binom ak=\binom {a}{a-k}
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Answer (score 3):

This is kind of strange since I thought you normally started with the second and then went to the first. Anyway, just multiply top and bottom of first definition by $(a-k)!$.

Comment: Excuse me, It's not really clear why I should do that.

Comment: To complete the $a!$ on top of the first definiton.

Comment: @SandeepSilwal: The definition above is for $a\in \mathbb{R}$, so the problem is basically asking the reader to show the more general definition agrees with the usual definition where possible.  But I agree it reads/feels kind of backwards.